# Skilled—Recognised Graduate visa (subclass 476)

Tags: visa, working-visas, immigration, australia, residency

Hope you all are fine, i have done Msc Operations and Supply chain management from school of engineering and technology University of Hertfordshire Hatfield UK. Moreover, i have checked it that my degree is accredited from Engineering council UK. but i have some confusion it comes under washington accord? and will i be eligible for Skilled—Recognised Graduate visa (subclass 476)?
tell me as soon as possible

Answer (score 2):

This is not a 100% answer, but will at least give you some more information. I first looked up the Washington Accord and found that [IET](http://www.ieagreements.org/Washington-Accord/Accredited.cfm) is the accrediting body in the UK.

I then looked at IET's website. You can search their [ACAD database](http://www.engc.org.uk/education-skills/course-search/acad/) to find accredited courses. I only put Hertfordshire in as a search term. Here's your course:

```
Course Title  Operations and Supply Chain Management  Course Ref  10649  Section  CEng  

Type              Award  Intake Year   Accredited By    Section 
1 years Full time  MSc   2011-2016       IET             CEng  
2 years Part time  MSc   2011-2016       IET             CEng  

Public Note(s) •Accredited further learning for CEng
```

However, this listing is whether a course is appropriate for licensing as a Civil Engineer which else states that a Msc in Civil Engineering would also need a BSc CEng for licensing.

I think, as pratap suggested, you will need to contact DIBP to clarify. Giving them this information may make it easier for them to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, By looking at your question u did "MSc from Hertfordshire university". No UK masters degree comes under Washington accord  accredited. it only shows your university is recognised or not, well Hertfordshire university is recognised university.
secondly, comes to your specialisation "Operations and supply chain management" you need to contact some consultant or DIBP AUSTRALIA. I am sure it is not listed in the recognised course.

Comment: acceptable answer u gave me, but my Masters of science ( operations and supply chain management ) which is part of Msc modular Production and manufacturing engineering Hertfordshire University. i have checked it that my masters is accredited by IET (Institute of engineering technology)